# Istio Gateway VirtualServices routing

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I'm attempting to setup a simple routing example with Istio 1.3.0-rc.0 based upon the Book Info example. I am attempting this in EKS with Kubernetes version 1.13. Here is my configuration.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: myapp-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: http
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - "*"

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp-service
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3001
      name: http
  selector:
    app: myapp

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp-v1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myapp
          image: fake-myapp:v1
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3001

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp-v2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
      version: v2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
        version: v2
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myapp
          image: fake-myapp:v2
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3001
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: myapp-destinationrule
spec:
  host: myapp-service
  subsets:
    - name: v1
      labels:
        version: v1
    - name: v2
      labels:
        version: v2

---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: app-virtualservice
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*"
  gateways:
    - myapp-gateway
  http:
    - match:
        - uri:
            exact: /api
      route:
        - destination:
            host: myapp-service
            subset: v2

---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: myapp-virtualservice
spec:
  hosts:
    - myapp-service
  http:
    - route:
        - destination:
            host: myapp-service
            subset: v2
---
```

I can reach my services from the external load balancer, however, I am attempting to route traffic to only subset v2 as is defined in my VirtualServices.

However, I only get round robin balancing between the two versions of my Deployment.

I've tried the [troubleshooting links](https://istio.io/docs/ops/traffic-management/troubleshooting/#route-rules-have-no-effect-on-ingress-gateway-requests) which suggest adding the subset to the VirtualService that has my gateway attached, but still without any success.

I've also tried setting a host name explicitly without luck.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Here are my observations particularly on the 2 `VirtualService`'s.

1. On the first VirtualService (`app-virtualservice`), the `match.uri` is `exact` with value `/api`. Which means request that exactly has path `/api` will work i.e. POST GATEWAY_URL/api, GET GATEWAY_URL/api. If you have some more extensions, e.g. POST GATEWAY_URL/api/somethingelse, then it won't fall into this routing. Kindly check on this area. If this is a problem, maybe use `prefix` instead of `exact`.
2. On the second VirtualService (`myapp-virtualservice`), there is no indication of `spec.gateways` which would specify the gateway it will apply. Also, in this particular instance, `VirtualService` governs the routing for your `Gateway`. The DestinationRules apply for the `Service` (or the Envoy sidecar proxy).

Please check and see if these helps.

Comment: Please refer to this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72391650/routing-not-worked-in-istio-ingress-gateway

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is quite explainable. Once you have created K8s [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) pointing to the two different [deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) `v1` and `v2`, K8s runtime composes certain [endpoints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#cloud-native-service-discovery) which are listening on the same port, therefore each time you reach application service throughout Istio mesh traffic objects path (*Gateway -> Virtual service -> Destination rule -> K8s service*) the request randomly hits `myapp-v1`, `myapp-v2` nested Pods, as per ***user space proxy*** [mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#proxy-mode-userspace), which is enabled using round robin algorithm by default.

You might probably need to compose two separate k8s services for `v1` and `v2` deployments, targeting appropriate endpoints respectively, in order to avoid sporadic traffic routing between application parties if you are expecting to route traffic between apps, instead of splitting traffic across the service [Subsets](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#service-subsets).

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp-v1-service
  labels:
    version: v1
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3001
      name: http
  selector:
    version: v1
```

---

```
apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: myapp-v2-service
      labels:
        version: v2
    spec:
      ports:
        - port: 3001
          name: http
      selector:
        version: v2
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Please refer to the official helloworld sample here: https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/samples/helloworld/helloworld.yaml. You may need to add **app** & **version** labels to your `Deployment` metadata and **targetPort** to your `Service`.
2. The `DestinationRule` yaml is correct.
3. The `VirtualService` yamls can be merged like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: myapp-service
spec:
  hosts:
  - myapp-service
  - myapp.com
  gateways:
  - myapp-gateway
  - mesh
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /api
      gateways:
      - myapp-gateway
    route:
    - destination:
        host: myapp-service
        subset: v2
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - mesh
    route:
    - destination:
        host: myapp-service
        subset: v2
```